# Extracting values from created resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I'm trying to automate creation of a few K8s resources using either helm or kustomize (the latter is preferred option). What I want to do is:

1. create a ServiceAccount
2. get value of its token, as you would do with `kubectl get secret <secret_name> -o jsonpath={.data.token}`
3. use the value from step #3 to create another Secret

This can be done pretty easily with CLI, but I want to wrap it using one of the templating tools. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it `use the value from step #2 to create another Secret`?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes can [create a Secret with a ServiceAccount token on its own](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-a-service-account-api-token).  In a Helm chart, this would look like

```yaml
# templates/sa-secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: "{{ template "mychart.fullname . }}-sa"
  labels:
    {{- template "mychart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "{{ template "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}"
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

As a more general statement, though, Helm doesn't have the ability to create some resources, stop and do something else, and then create other resources; it only creates and deletes Kubernetes resources in one big block.  This case only works because you can describe it using Kubernetes YAML.